# What are the best ways to manage challenges to the storyteller?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

The rules list various subjective ways players can force a storyteller to end her turn when she:

- Gets stuck
- Contradicts the story
- Rambles
- Is too silly
- Introduces unimportant elements

What have you found are the smoothest or best ways to handle these challenges? Do you simply put it to a majority vote, a unanimous vote? Are there problems that often occur like spirited agreement to the challenges by people simply wanting to get more of an edge toward winning?

I'm looking for insights on what people have found works better and what sort of stumbling blocks they encountered with this aspect of a game that clearly requires people to be on the same page and somewhat sporting of each other to truly make it work.

Or drunk.

Comment: As soon as I started reading the question I was going to comment that it helps to drink, then I saw the last line. Nail, Head. Also it helps to remember that it is just a game; don't take it so seriously or you will end up spoiling the concept of a collaborative story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This highly depends on your playgroup composition and style:

In my usual gaming group (2-8 adults looking for light, social gaming with only a minor interest in who actually wins), we use a basic **majority voting** like Wolfkin described - when someone thinks a turn should end, he says so, and everyone quickly nods / raises a hand / mumbles 'uh-ha' or 'naaa' etc. Anything that's quick enough so it doesn't slow the flow of the game. It's also quite common for the **storyteller to voluntary end their own turn** when they get stuck etc.

On the other hand, the group that introduced the game to me had several very competitive players, and there another limitation was required - **the player to the left of the storyteller can't raise objections** (i.e. the one who'll become storyteller next if the vote to end the turn passes) - This was necessary to prevent some players from raising an objection every second sentence...

Finally, when playing with my younger relatives (a group of 2-4 young children and 1-3 adults), we usually have **one of the adults double as a referee** - leaving it to him to call for turn changes, optionally raising it to a vote.

As RM Bee said, this game doesn't really work that well when played too competitively or seriously.

Answer (score 4):

For my money the simple thumbsup system works with my group. You're welcome to tell the story and if someone contradicts or uses a card for a nonessential element you call an audible and stick out your hand thumbs down. You have about five seconds and then everyone else joins in thumbs up or thumbs down. Majority rules.

The rest of the time if the story teller is rambling you can just stick out your hand thumbs down and as they go if more people join your thumbs down and it reaches majority then you lose and the story passes on.

Comment: One of the benefits is that if you are a teller that is rambling and someone sticks out a thumbs down, then you know they're call you out on your rambling and it's a form of pressure to make you get to the point (if you have one). As more people join in that's more pressure for to short cut to the point (again if you have one) and if you don't have one it's pressure to just admit it and pass your turn.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that first, this is a game that is not meant to be played competitively or seriously. Second, disputes concerning challenges to the storyteller are generally best resolved by a concensus built among those neither challenging nor being challenged.  Given that people in this category  normally form a group no larger than 3, this consensus is generally quite achievable.